# Using pandas in a csv modified file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

is it possible to use pandas after rewriting data into a csv using something like this:

```
import csv
headers = []

cleaned_data = open('cleaned_data.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(cleaned_data)

for row in open("house_prices.csv"):
# <-- Some body code here to filter out the headers
```

This is where I want to continue with my cleaning of data and get rid of rows that contain missing values. I've been told that using pandas is the way to go but I'm not sure if it's ok to do it since the first steps are to write this code:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('house_prices.csv')
```

which conflicts with my first code, right? So is it possible to remove rows of missing values with this method or is there another way without importing anything?

Or would it be possible to combine both?ie:

```py
import csv
import pandas as pd
headers = []

cleaned_data = open('cleaned_data.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(cleaned_data)

df = pd.read_csv('house_prices.csv')
df.dropna(axis=0, how='any', thresh=None, subset=None, inplace=False)

for row in open("house_prices.csv"):
# <-- Some body code here to filter out the headers
```

Would that work? This is the first time I'm seeing pandas

Comment: The typical workflow in pandas is to read the **entire** file (or large chunks if too memory intensive), use vectorized operations to clean/modify **all** of the data at once, and then export **all** of the data back to a different file. So generally you avoid things like `for row in df.iterrows()` in favor of `df._some_vectorized_operation_that_does_the_same`

Comment: Can you show a sample of the data you're trying to clean? I think this can be done in Pandas, but it's hard to tell without seeing the data.

Comment: ```2009 2010 2011 2012 2013



ABBOTSFORD 652000 736000 730000 714000 792500 


ABERFELDIE 786500 1046500 994000 852500 947500```

something like that where the first rows are years, and the first column is the name and the rest are numbers